# Filter event objects by body content

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, odata

I'm trying to query calendar events using the Graph API and I would like to filter them by category and body content.

The goal is to get any event object that is in category "Test" and contains the string "FooBar" in its body content.

I tried to query the Graph API with the following request:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$filter=(categories/any(x:x eq 'Test') and contains(body/content, 'FooBar'))`

The response is a 500 error message:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInternalServerError",
        "message": "An internal server error occurred. The operation failed.",
        //...
    }
}
```

The "categories" filter clause works fine on its own but as soon as I put the "body/content" clause back in I get the aforementioned error response.

The json object I get from the Graph API looks like this (stripped down for better readability)

```json
{
    "value": [
        {
            "categories": [
                "Test"
            ],
            "bodyPreview": "FooBar",
            "body": {
                "contentType": "html",
                "content": "<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"></head><body><div class=\"BodyFragment\"></div><div class=\"BodyFragment\"><font size=\"2\"><span style=\"font-size:11pt\"><div class=\"PlainText\">FooBar</div></span></font></div></body></html>"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there something wrong with my filter clause or might this be an issue with Graph API itself?
I first tried to filter by `bodyPreview` but the error response I got clearly said that this field cannot be filtered by so I guess body/content should be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filtering by body/content is not supported for `events`.

I've tried similar query for `messages` and it works fine, so your filter clause is correct.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=(categories/any(x:x eq 'Test') and contains(body/content, 'FooBar'))
```

Comment: Is there a way to filter events by it's body content?

Comment: @dchang I'm afraid that there is no way

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that was my conclusion